# integrate a week-schedule from google sheets into webnode website

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-workspace

I have a weekly schedule on a google sheet that I´d like to integrate into a webnode website. I tried the embed html but the results are poor when viewed on the phone. Moreover, I tried exporting to google calendar and embeding the calendar, but I cannot seem to control the default calendar dates and optimally I´d like the webpage to only display sun-frid in a certain week. The codyhouse template schedule looks awesome, but I have no clue as to how I can take data from google sheets and automatically generate the required html (except for doing in manually). Any other good ideas how this can be done?

Comment: Can you share an example of the table you want? What is the issue when you see the table in a phone?

Comment: Please see the following [link](https://codyhouse.co/demo/schedule-template/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is complicated as the [example](https://codyhouse.co/demo/schedule-template/index.html) you provided is complex. However, I can give you some tips to create an html table using data from Sheets:

You can get the data of each cell with the [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues()) method. This generates a 2D array (rows and cloumns of the table). For example:

`var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A1:F11").getValues();`

Then you can nest a `for` loop inside another to generate a string containing the html code and the values of the table:

```
var htmlString = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body>';
for (var i = 0; i < values[0].length; i++){

    htmlString += '<tr>'+values[i];

    for (var j = 0; j < values.length; j++){

        htmlString += '<th>'+values[j][i]+'</th>';
    }

    htmlString += '</tr>';
}
 htmlString += '</body></html>'
```